# Selenium - How to get text after image tag

Tags: java, selenium, dom, xpath

```
<ul class="meta">
   <li class="user">
       <img class="classname" src="some url">
       givemetext               
   </li>
</ul>
```

I want to grab text "givemetext" by finding the element and using .getText(); The catch is thou I already grab a surrounding element and am doing something like this "

```
List<WebElement> user = i.findElements(By.xpath("../ul[@class='meta']/li[@class='user']"));
System.out.println("username! " + user.get(0).getText());
```

'i' is the for each element that I already found. I also tried adding /img to the xpath but no text is found. Any direction be great! Thanks. This is java btw (If you couldn't see from System.out ;).

Answer (score 1):

<s>The text may be associated with the img tag since it follows the img tag.  So maybe something like:</s>

```
List<WebElement> user = i.findElements(By.xpath("../ul[@class='meta']/li[@class='user']/img"));
System.out.println("username! " + user.get(0).getText());
```

I haven't tried it locally but that is what I would try next.

**Update**

I got the following to work locally:

```
WebElement listItem = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/ul/li"));


String text = "";
if (driver instanceof JavascriptExecutor) {
    text = (String)((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(
        "var nodes = arguments[0].childNodes;" +
        "var text = '';" +
        "for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {" +
        "    if (nodes[i].nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE) {" +
        "        text += nodes[i].textContent;" +
        "    }" +
        "}" +
        "return text;"
        , listItem);
    }
    System.out.println(text);
}
```

Comment: Ya that was one of the first things I tried. It didn't work. I think its because img tag is already closed.

Comment: See the updated answer. BTW, whoever came up with the idea of text nodes is way smarter than me.

Comment: You will still have to trim() because the preceding and trailing whitespace contained in the text node(s) is still returned.  Perhaps if the HTML looked like: <img class="classname" src="some url">givemetext</li> then there would be no whitespace to trim.

Comment: very dirty ahah jk its better than mine because i have to trim the img tag, so i like it, but its almost less lines to just trim the innerhtml than that. That being said i love the creativity. Plus 1.

Comment: Thank you. It has the advantage of always working.  I have a function version of this that I keep in my tool kit. Text nodes can be such a pain.

Answer (score 0):

If I do user.get(0).getAttribute("innerHTML");

returns me everything with img tag, I guess that will work, I will just trim away.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the htmlunit.html;
and xpath like this :

```
List<HtmlElement> htmlElementList = htmlBody.getByXPath(xpathExpr);

String xmlTextBody = htmlElementList.get(0).getTextContent()
```

Answer (score -1):

to get the text after img tag u can write the xpath like following:
    WebElement ele=     findElement(By.xpath("//ul/li/img[text()='giventext'));
System.out.println("text of element"+ele.getText());

Comment: I wouldn't be grabbing it if I already knew what the text was.